# Use "accede" or "agree"?

Tags: word-usage

I just want to know whether the word *accede* in the following sentence makes it formal or would it be better if I swap the word *accede* with *agree* in spoken language?

> When my friends told me about the trip they had planned, I acceded
>   to it without much further thought.

PS: I am trying to apply newly learnt words while I have a conversation.

Comment: This word strikes me as potentially confusing depending on your audience, as it is somewhat less common. That isn't necessarily a bad thing or a reason not to use it; however, it is something to keep in mind when choosing the most appropriate word for a certain context.

Comment: As a minor unrelated point, it should be "when my friends **told** me"; *said* does not take an indirect object.

Comment: @Hellion: Point noted :)

Comment: You should also say "I acceded/agreed ***to go***," rather than "to it". "It" refers back to "the trip", which isn't what you're agreeing to. You're agreeing *to go* on the trip. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd To me, it sounds ok to leave out "to go" here, and say "when my friends told me about the trip, I agreed to it." I think it would be normal for me to say "when my husband told me about the formal dinner, I reluctantly agreed to it" or "when my parents told me about the vacation, I gladly agreed to it".

Comment: @aediaλ I'm not saying it wouldn't be understood, and maybe some people speak that way. But technically it doesn't make any sense. "When he asked me to dance, I agreed to it (agreed to dance)" makes sense. "When my husband *asked me to come to* the formal dinner, I reluctantly agreed to it (agreed to come)" makes sense. "When they told me about the trip, I agreed to it (agreed to the trip)" doesn't technically make semantic sense. But yes, it's definitely understandable :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I disagree with @Matt that *accede* would not necessarily be understood by many native speakers, I will agree that its usage is uncommon, and it is probably considered an "unnecessarily highbrow" sort of word.
Also, *accede* has a connotation that may be undesired: it is usually used in the context of "giving in", that is, changing your position as the result of a demand or strong request.  Whatever you are acceding to was not your first choice or preference.  With that in mind, "acceding to (their trip)" is probably not a suitable phrase unless (a) they really wanted you to go and (b) you had other plans originally.

Comment: In the context of giving in, a much more common word would be "concede" rather than "accede". The **only** use of accede that I've seen in evenly vaguely common use (as a native British English speaker) is *royal assent* in the context of a drafted law by parliament being given a royal signature and passing into law officially (and possibly to *accede the throne*). I've certainly never heard it used by an ordinary person used to mean that they agree to something.

Comment: @Matt -- "Accede" falls somewhere between "agree" and "concede".  "Agree" implies wholehearted acceptance.  "Concede" means to give in.  "Accede" is closer to "okay, I'll go along with your proposal, but it wouldn't have been my first choice."  (Native US speaker, of an "older generation".)

Comment: @Matt, I am more likely to concede a point and accede to a demand.  I might also make a concession in response to a demand, but to me "making a concession" implies partial fulfillment of the demand, while "acceding" is complete fulfillment.

Comment: +1 for making the (not unduly optimistic, imho) point that many if not most native speakers (discounting children and other linguistically-challenged people) would *understand* "accede". Everyone has a reasonable understanding of many words they would only very rarely (or indeed, *never*) use themselves. And I completely agree your point that "accede" implies "giving in" more than "agree" does. Although "agreed" is more common than "acceded" overall, I bet the latter is proportionately more likely to be preceded by "eventually", for example.

Answer (score 8):

Although accede is a valid word, it is exceptionally rarely used, and "I accede" would not be understood by many native speakers:

[image]

If you needed a formal alternative to *agree*, you could perhaps choose:

> I **concur** (formal, perhaps a little pompous)
>
> I **consent** (esp. to agree to something in a legal context)
>
> I **permit** it (i.e. to give permission for it to happen)

In spoken language however most of the above would come across as excessively formal. Most native speakers would simply go with *agree*:

> I **agreed** to it without further thought.

Answer (score 3):

To "accede" is to be persuaded by someone else, against your own instincts. It does NOT mean to agree "naturally."

Answer (score 0):

To add to environments where this might be appropriately used - Accede is used in legal context quite commonly. I had to look this up as counsel in a trial used it a few times. For example in this way -  'I accede to your proposition'. It does imply 'giving in' rather than readily agreeing, as previous posts have mentioned.